# mysql select n rows starting at row x loop to beginning of table if necessary

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to select a given number of rows starting at a given row number, *looping to the beginning of the table if necessary*?

The following does not work if the sum of `$starting_offset` and `$limit` is greater than the number of rows in the table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY sort_order ASC
LIMIT $starting_offset, $limit
```

I need to always select `$limit` number of rows, unless there are less then `$limit` rows in the table.

Comment: That is default behavior, if after a given offset, number of records are not that much that you want, it will return only available records.

Comment: just select the number of rows first

Comment: @JitendraYadav What I want to do is loop back to the beginning of the table rather then 'returning only available records'.

Comment: Oh got it. Sorry I missed that part

Comment: where $starting_offset does come from? why can't you adjust it before running the query

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't understand, are you referring to a sub-query?

Comment: i am referring to an **extra** query you are running every time a pagination is used

Comment: @YourCommonSense $starting_offset comes from the sort_order of a previously selected item. I just asked the question because it seemed like there must be an elegant way to do it in a single mysql query. Perhaps it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  (
  SELECT * 
  FROM table
  ORDER BY sort_order ASC
  LIMIT $starting_offset, $limit
  ) AS table1
  UNION ALL
  (
  SELECT * 
  FROM table
  ORDER BY sort_order ASC
  LIMIT $limit
  ) AS table2
)
ORDER BY sort_order ASC
LIMIT $limit
```

The first subquery attempts to get `$limit` rows starting at `$offset`. The second subquery gets the *first* `$limit` matching rows (i.e. starting at offset 0), so if the first subquery returns fewer than `$limit` rows, the second subquery will "fill in" the remainder, guaranteeing you a total of `$limit` rows in your result set (assuming there are at least that many to begin with).

Also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167768/perform-mysql-limited-select-that-wraps-when-it-reaches-the-end-of-table

Edit: Added final `ORDER BY` clause (optional if you always want the results sorted).

Comment: You'd still need a further ORDER BY clause

Comment: Thanks, just added it!

Comment: However, that makes it difficult to tell which "page" you're on, if that really matters. So I would say it depends on the user's requirements.

Comment: No. If there's no ORDER BY, then the optimiser is free to return the rows in any order. But perhaps you can think of a minor modification to your query that solves the problem you've identified ;-)

Comment: So you're saying that `UNION ALL` might change the order of the rows returned by the query, even though the two inner `ORDER BY` clauses will always put them in a certain order? Interesting, I didn't think of that. In that case, how about having the first query also select `ROW_NUMBER() AS r`, the second query select `ROW_NUMBER() + 1 + $limit AS r`, and the outer (main) query `ORDER BY r`?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER might work, but there is (in my view) a simpler method

Comment: Ok, I give up: please tell!

Comment: I'm not going to tell, but it starts by naming columns instead of using (evil) `SELECT *`